# Can I use async / await to simulate a background worker?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to avoid having to chain a bunch of BackgroundWorkers together.  I'm doing something that requires me to wait for the UI to update before continuing execution.  Obviously, I can't use Sleep, as this blocks the UI thread from updating and defeats the purpose.  I found the code below which I thought was the answer, but it appears the `task.Wait();` line is still blocking the UI thread.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
    task.Wait();
    // once the task completes, now do more
}

static void DoSomething()
{
    // something here that is looking for the UI to change
}
```

I also tried the following, which did the same thing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => DoSomethingAsync());
    task.Wait();
    // once the task completes, now do more
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    // something here that is looking for the UI to change
}
```

Is it possible to do what I want, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER EVER use `Task.Wait()`, it is almost guaranteed to produce a deadlock.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `await` the task instead of blocking on it. You can do that inside an `async` method.

Now, `Main` can't be `async` but an event handler can be (which I guess is where you actually use that code):

```
public async void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoSomething()); // wait asynchronously
    // continue on the UI thread
}
```

Note that it's `async void` which should only be used on event handlers. All other `async` methods should return a task.

Using `Task.Run` means your using a ThreadPool thread. To really wait asynchronously for the UI to "do something" you should use `TaskCompletionSource`. You create it and `await` it's `Task` property and you complete that task when the UI changed:

```
public async void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    await _tcs.Task;
}

public void UIChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tcs.SetResult(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this finally fixed my issue.  I was a little confused because when I used the "await" line as you mentioned, it gave me an error that made it sound like it wanted my DoSomethingAsync() method marked as async, which of course it already was.  But it actually wanted me to put the async modifier on the event (which you showed, but I didn't quite catch at first).  Thanks.

Comment: [Avoid `async void` methods](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/), use `async Task` instead.

Comment: @newbieguy  "Note that it's async void which should only be used on event handlers. All other async methods should return a task."

Comment: "Main can't be async". Now we can, framework 4.7.2. Enjoy!

Comment: @aldo It's a feature of the language.. so from C# 7.1.